# Symfony 4 - Using an array to create form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm looking for a way to create an embeded form using Symfony 4.
I used a queryn this query returns me an array. But When I execute the code the following error appear :

> The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class
>   App\Entity\Categorie, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of
>   App\Entity\Categorie.

So my controller looks like this :

```php
    /**
     * @Route("/admin/categories/import/{userId}", name="admin.categorie.link", methods={"GET|POST"})
     * @param Int $userId
     * @return Response
     */
    public function linkImport(Int $userId, Request $request)
    {

        $categories = $this->em->getRepository(Categorie::class)->checkIfNew($userId);


            $form = $this->createForm(CategorieType::class, $categories);

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                $this->em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('success', 'Catalogue modifié avec succès');
                return $this->redirectToRoute('admin.catalogues.index');
            }

            return $this->render('admin/catalogues/link.html.twig', [
                'categories' => $categories,
                'form' => $form->createView()
            ]);
    }
```

And my form type looks like this :

```
class CategorieType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('categorie_intitule')
            ->add('categorie_parent_id')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Categorie::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I've tried to use a foreach to build the form

```
foreach ($categories as $categorie) {
    $form = $this->createForm(CategorieType::class, $categorie);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

}
```

But it returns me notinhg inside my twig.
So Can you please tell me a bit more about this error, and how to fix it ?
Thank you.

**UPDATE :** According to @DoncCallisto answer I've tried the following thing :

I create a CategorieCollectionType :

```php
class CategorieCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('categories', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CategorieType::class,
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Categorie::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

And change this inside my controller :

```php
$categories = $this->em->getRepository(Categorie::class)->checkIfNew($userId);


            $form = $this->createForm(CategorieCollectionType::class, ['categories' => $categories]);
```

But the error is still the same.
Here is a dump from `$categories` from the Symfony debug :

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => App\Entity\Categorie {#1395 ▼
    -id: 52
    -categorie_intitule: "-"
    -categorie_parent_id: null
    -produitCategorie_id: Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection {#1451 ▶}
    -created_by: App\Entity\User {#1039 ▶}
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CategorieType` is a single form for a single `Category`.
If you need to display all of them, maybe you should wrap `CategorieType` *inside* another form (like `CategorieCollectionType`).

More ore less, something like

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

class CategorieCollectionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('categories', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => CategorieType::class, // remember to import it via "use"
            ])
        );
    }
}
```

and use it within controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(CategorieCollectionType::class, ['categories' => $categories]);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you answer, I've tried your solution but the error persist... Did I need to add few thing to My CategorieCollectionType or CategorieTYpe ?
+ Btw I suppose you mean I need to use `$form = $this->createForm(CategorieCollectionType::class, ['categories' => $categories]);` Right ?

Comment: The error message is the same : `The form's view data is expected to be an instance of class App\Entity\Categorie, but is a(n) array. You can avoid this error by setting the "data_class" option to null or by adding a view transformer that transforms a(n) array to an instance of App\Entity\Categorie.`

Comment: @Newbiedev Quite strange, are you sure you're following my example? It should work, I can't see any reason for this to still show that message, unless `$categories` is an arrays of array.

Comment: I've updated my question with the code I try and a dumb from `$categories` Did I need to change something inside the `configureOption` from `CategorieCollectionType` ? I've changed nothing ?

Comment: @Newbiedev remove the `configureOption` method from `CategorieCollectionType` (I was not reporting it in my example). It should be left only in `CategorieType`

Comment: I'm sorry I made the mistake....Thank you a lot for your help :)